# jQuery click on row from mysql db in php not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This should be really simple but what i'm doing is pulling data from a mysql db in php into a table and what i'd like to do is when i click a cell in the ID column, for it to turn white. i can get that to work but once it does one it doesnt do another!?

```
$('#addtocart').click(function(){
                $('#addtocart').css("color","white");
                return false;
});
```

In my php i'm doing this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {       
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td id='addtocart'>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['om_part_no'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['supplier_part_no'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['list_price'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['discount'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['price_each_nett'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</tbody>
                </table>";
```

Should this be causing me this many problems!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing that only for the element with id="addtocart".

I would change it and make it that every element with class="addtocart" onclick will become white.

`$('.addtocart').click(function(){

                $(this).css("color","white");

                return false;

});`

And use `echo "td class='addtocart'" . $row['id'] . "";` onstead of ID. You should not have more than one element with the same ID.

P.S. How to add tabs in my code?

Comment: So would change anything in the PHP code? if i "inspect element" in Firefox every cell in the id column has an id of "addtocart"...but no luck!

Comment: Just make it class="addtocart" not id="addtoclass". You could not many element with the same ID. The ID is unique for the document.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some mistakes:
1) Where is your open table tag `<table>`?
2) Is jQuery script included in to html?
3) Try to make the next thing. It can be helpful:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#addtocart').click(function(){
      $('#addtocart').css("color","white");
      return false;
   });
});
```

4) Install `Firebug` add-on for Firefox for debug JS errors.
5) `Id` should be an unique value. But you have more than 1 element with same id. Try to generate unique id.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the PHP is fine, i'm also using jQuery plugin "TableData" not sure if that is interfering!? I've done all the 3 things you put down...